# What's that line on the bazooka's firing gauge mean?

Tags: warmux

I've been playing Warmux for a long time, but I've never figured out what that little line on the bazooka's firing gauge means:

[image: Merciless Elephant Slaughter with Freehand Circle]

At first I thought that it might be a guide on how hard to fire it to hit an enemy, since it seems like the AIs often stop there, but it only changes every turn, not actively during your turn. What does it mean?

Comment: Is it not like worms in the fact that it will be the force placed behind the object fired That game looks like a copy of worms lol :D

Comment: Yes, it is an open-source Worms-like game, and that is what the bar means. I'm asking what the little circled line means though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't played it, but in similar games it marks the power of the last shot.

Comment: You are correct sir. Just tested it, and can confirm it marks the power of the last shot.